# How to redirect?

Tags: redirect

I have this code here - and I'm inserting this in a plugin file. Basically I want to set it so that if a person accesses the direct link of the post ID (524), it will redirect back to homepage. But if the person comes from the domain it will work. Found this code somewhere and tweaked it but I think there are some errors.

```
if( $post->ID == 524) {
  return;
} if (wp_get_referer() == 'the domain') {
    return;
  }
  wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
}
```

Comment: You should also use `exit()` or `die()` after redirecting.

Comment: @JackJohansson - where would I use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
add_action('wp','special_redirect');

function special_redirect(){

  global $post;

  if( $post->ID ==  123 ) // put your post id
  { 
    if ( ! wp_get_referer() ) // false if you access directly 
    {
        wp_safe_redirect( get_home_url() ); // if so redirect to home
    }
  }
}
```

It should work. I've tested it.

Comment: You should consider this to be an accepted answer then.